# How to enter text in a fieldset's summary?

Tags: forms

Using the form api to create a fieldset:

```
$form['fieldset'] = array(
 '#title' => 'title',
 '#type' => 'fieldset',
 '#collapsible' => TRUE,
 '#description' => 'desc',
);
```

Drupal will output:

```
<fieldset class="collapsible form-wrapper collapse-processed" id="edit-fieldset">
  <legend>
    <span class="fieldset-legend">
      <a class="fieldset-title" href="#">
        <span class="fieldset-legend-prefix element-invisible">Hide</span>
         title
      </a>
      <span class="summary"></span>
    </span>
  </legend>
  <div class="fieldset-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-testelement">
      <label for="edit-testelement">asdf </label>
      <input type="text" id="edit-testelement" name="testelement" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The #title in the form array will be the `<a>` you click on to expand the fieldset.  I want to put text in the `<span class="summary"></span>`, which puts additional, non linked text beside the title.  I can't seem to do this with the form api, as #description will only put text within the fieldset that is hidden when it is closed.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

See [`vertical_tabs_example_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/vertical_tabs_example!vertical_tabs_example.module/function/vertical_tabs_example_form_alter/7), there it's written:

> Vertical tabs provide its most usable appearance when they are used to
>   include a summary of the information contained in the fieldset. To do
>   this, we attach additional JavaScript to handle changing the summary
>   when form settings are changed.

```
  '#attached' => array(
    'js' => array(
      'vertical-tabs' => drupal_get_path('module', 'vertical_tabs_example') . '/vertical_tabs_example.js',
    ),
  ),
```

In `vertical_tabs_example.js` it then goes on like so:

> Use the fieldset class to identify the vertical tab element. Depending
>   on the checkbox status, the settings will be customized, so update the
>   summary with the custom setting textfield string or a use a default
>   string.

```
$('fieldset#edit-vertical-tabs-example', context).drupalSetSummary(function (context) {
  if ($('#edit-vertical-tabs-example-enabled', context).attr('checked')) {
    return Drupal.checkPlain($('#edit-vertical-tabs-example-custom-setting', context).val());
  }
  else {
    return Drupal.t('Using default');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I am looking to do something similar, setting a summary in a manually output collapsible fieldset.

I looked into the collapse.js where it is defining the collapse behavior (line 56 of /misc/collapse.js).

At line 70, It looks like it is pulling the summary text from [$.fn.drupalGetSummary()](http://drupalapi.attiks.com/api/drupal/misc!form.js/function/%24.fn.drupalGetSummary/7).

I am not 100% on this (since it doesn't appear to mention in the Form API docs), but from looking at source codes, I think it might do the trick if you add to your array an entry for

```
'#summary' => "This is my fieldset!",
```

Other things you could experiment with:

```
'#summary callback' => 'my_module_example_fieldset_summary',
'#summary arguments' => array('bar'),
```

and you would probably need to define the summary callback in a module...

```
function my_module_example_fieldset_summary($foo){
  return t("foo is ".$foo.".");
}
```

or maybe you could just use something simple like:

```
'#summary callback' => 't',
'#summary arguments' => array('foo is bar.'),
```

Comment: `$.fn.drupalGetSummary()` is a JavaScript function; it cannot call any PHP function.